# How to display names and IP addresses of devices connected to a network using C++

Tags: c++, windows, networking, ip-address

I am making a program where I have to use TCP/IP connection to transmit and receive data between devices. I would like to be able to detect the names and IP addresses of all devices that are using the network(The device running the program is also on the network). I am using C++ on windows, I looked through the Windows Native Wifi API but couldn't find anything. Is there an efficient way to get the names and IP addresses of all devices connected to the network?

Comment: Why do you think you need this information?   The overwhelming majority of TCP/IP applications don't, and those that do (e.g. LAN games) tend to rely on a broadcast or multicast discovery mechanism to find other hosts _already running the same application_.

Comment: I would like to be able to select the device that I want to send and receive data from without having to check its IP address whenever I switch networks or want to switch device

Comment: Usually you don't select bare devices, you select devices that are already running some service.   Those services often announce themselves to the network via some other channel.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few competing techniques, such as Apple Bonjour. That's pretty much a clue that there is no single way that gives you all names of all devices - this is not standard IP-level functionality.